# How to make a widget attached to QTabWidget's gap and move accordingly with QSplitter in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qsplitter

I want to make the button always next to the second tab's label, even when I use splitter to move the edge between two tabs. How to achieve that? I believe it's because I use the absolute position, but how make an widget attached in the gap in QTabWidget?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, 
    QSplitter, QStyleFactory, QApplication,QTabWidget,QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        tab1 = QTabWidget(self)
        tab2 = QTabWidget(self)


        a=QWidget()
        a.setGeometry(0,0, 40, 40)
        tab2.addTab(a,"2")

        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter1.addWidget(tab1)
        splitter1.addWidget(tab2)
        splitter1.setSizes([100,100])
        hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        z=QPushButton(self)
        z.setGeometry(100,100,70,20)
        z.setText("button")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is what I want to achieve all the time.

[image: This is what I want to achieve all the time]

This is what happened when I adjust the edge between two tabs.

[image: This is what happened when I adjust the edge between two tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a parent to a widget, the widget has a coordinate system relative to the parent, so you must change the parent. In addition to adjusting the position of the button to one relative to the parent:

```
[...]
z=QPushButton(tab2)
z.setGeometry(100,0,70,20)
z.setText("button")
[...]
```

Another series improvement that even if the size of the QtabWidget changes, the button remains centered:

```
class TabWidgetWithButton(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = QPushButton("button", self)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.button.move((self.width()-self.button.width())/2, 0)
        QTabWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        tab1 = QTabWidget(self)
        tab2 = TabWidgetWithButton(self)

        a=QWidget(self)
        tab2.addTab(a,"2")
        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter1.addWidget(tab1)
        splitter1.addWidget(tab2)
        splitter1.setSizes([100,100])
        hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and thoughtful answer!